# Finding range of cells with value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data like this

```
A                        B  
7/17/2013        $4,000.00 
7/17/2013        $460.00 
7/17/2013        $(2,147.00)
7/17/2013        $(3,585.00)
7/17/2013        $(20,364.00)
7/18/2013        $(1,292.00)
7/18/2013        $1,910.00 
7/18/2013        $1,293.00 
7/18/2013        $1,729.00
```

I want to write a function that finds all cells in A with a date value and sums up its corresponding value in B. How do I do that?

Comment: Are there other data type in column A? Or is it simply a mix of date values and blank cells? Or, are you looking for a *particular* date value?  Please update your question to include more detail about your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like?

```
=SUMIF(A1:A12,"7/17/2013",B1:B12)
```

Of course change the ranges to match your data, the first range is the criteria range, then the date, then the sum range

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pivot table with A in the row labels and Sum of B in the values.

If you would rather write a function, in column C, make a list of all the dates you are interested in, then in column D, use the function =SUMIF($A$1:$A$12,C1,$B$1:$B$12).  This will sum the total $$ for each date you have in column C.